# Trouble with basic communication between two NRF24L01 modules

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, nrf24l01+

### Introduction

I am trying to setup a radio communication using the NRF24L01 module because I want to use it to control a tank. The first thing I did when I got the modules was watching some basic tutorials on youtube, for reference I watched HowToMecharonics' video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rcVeFFHcFM

"Arduino Tutorial: Arduino NRF24L01 Wireless Tutorial with Arduino Uno"

At first I tried to rewrite the code myself to see if I got the concept, but all of my attempts failed, so I tried to copy-paste his exact code and use the arduino IDE, but it didn't work.

Later I noticed that the setup only worked if I plugged both arduinos to the PC, they don't work when plugged in a power supply.
The receiver is an arduino MEGA and the transmitter an UNO.
When I unplug the UNO the IDE says "avrdude: ser_drain(): read error: The device does not recognize the command."

### Question

If I unplug the receiver it just doesn't work until I plug it back in, but no error pops up.

It seems strange to me that both arduinos have to be plugged yo the computer at al times, am I doing something wrong?
I also noticed that my modules are slightly different from the ones shown in the viedo, mine doesn't have a label below it

### Code

TX

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
}

void loop() {
  const char text[] = "Hello World";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
  delay(1000);
}
```

RX

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();
  Serial.println("working");
}

void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    char text[32] = "";
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  }
}
```